# Comparing current element to any element in the list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new to Python and don't know if there is any method to compare current value in a for loop iteration to any other previous occurrence. For example I have a list of tuples:

```
l = [(2.1, 310, 315), (1.2, 415, 460), (2.1, 310, 330), (1.2, 445, 470),
     (1.1, 335, 360), (1.1, 350, 410), (2.1, 310, 370)]
```

The first element in each tuple shows the ID, second the car arrival time and third the car depart time. A car cannot be at the same ID while another one is there for example here the first, third and last tuple. The third and last should go to waiting as the same ID and arrival time exist already. I know how to compare `i` and `i-1` value but how do I compare my `i` value to any previous values?

Comment: Use a dictionary and map every id to its relevant tuple, so before you try to _insert_ a new tuple, first check if the ID is not there already and if it is - handle it the way you find proper. `d = { 2.1: (2.1, 310, 315), 1.2: (1.2, 415, 460), ...}`

Answer (score 0):

Create a nested list like this:

```
list = [
  [2.1,310,315],
  [1.2,415,460],
  [2.1,310,330],
  [1.2,445,470],
  [1.1,335,360],
  [1.1,350,410],
  [2.1,310,370]
]
```

And you can access the value like this

```
list[0][0]
```

Result : 2.1
And use that for comparing the values

Answer (score 0):

For the most part all I can think of off the top of my head is a dual for loop.
Mind you tuples can be compared together for your future knowledge.
The code below *seems* to give the answer you need.

Notice I am storing each of the previous values in a tuple ready for the next iteration to observe, so it fixes your problem with being able to all the previous observed values.

```py
l = [(2.1,310,315),(1.2,415,460),(2.1,310,330),(1.2,445,470),(1.1,335,360),(1.1,350,410),(2.1,310,370)]
storage = []

for tuple_val in l:
    id = tuple_val[0]
    arrive = tuple_val[1]
    depart = tuple_val[2]
    waiting = False
    for previous_element in storage:
        id_prev = previous_element[0]
        arrive_prev = previous_element[1]
        depart_prev = previous_element[2]
        if id == id_prev and arrive < depart_prev and arrive >= arrive_prev:
            waiting = True
    storage.append((id, arrive, depart, waiting))
```